# How do Arrays behave in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, ios, arrays, null, behavior

I've always had my doubts about Arrays.

If an Array's count is 7, and I replace the SECOND elements with 'NULL', does it still have count 7?

If an Array's count is 7, and I replace the LAST elements with 'NULL', does it still have count 7? Or will it have count 6?

I need to know this behavior to make a function that removes the first element of the Array (place '0'), and the other elements of the Array swap one place to the front.

```
- (void) eat {
    [foodArray replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:NULL];
    for (int i = 0; i<[foodArray count]-1; ++i){
        [foodArray replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:[foodArray objectAtIndex:i+1]];
    }
    [foodArray replaceObjectAtIndex:[foodArray count]-1 withObject:NULL];
}
```

Would that work?

(Thanks!)

Edit: I've just noticed the first line isn't necessary, as I'm already replacing the first element later. Am I wrong?

Comment: Trying to put `NULL` into an `NSMutableArray` causes an exception. Did you even try this out?

Comment: I would suggest using NSPointerArray if you were on mac, but since you are not, take a look at CCArray in the cocos2d library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove an object from an array, just use [foodArray removeObjectAtIndex:]. The way you're doing it you're just leaving a null value in the array.

Comment: If the Array was [@"Apple", @"Pear", @"Banana", @"Orange"], I want it to become [@"Pear", @"Banana", @"Orange"].

If I remove the object at Index '0' with that function, will the object that was at index '1' be then at '0'?

Comment: @DavidDaSilvaContín Yes, if you remove a value, all following values are moved. A NSArray has no gaps.

Comment: Thanks! Then, the function is perfect for my need!

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the item:

```
- (void) eat {
    [foodArray removeObjectAtIndex:0];
}
```

Inorder to add/remove array elements the array must be mutable: `NSMutableArray` so foodArray must be a `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: @DavidDaSilvaContín Just making sure because the declaration was not given.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to keep NULL in an array is bad idea in general.
If you need to use some kind of placeholder - it's better to use an instance of NSNull class.

Later you can check type of the object using class name check:

```
if( [objectFromArray isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]] == YES )
    { // This is NSNull instance, not real object }
```

Comment: It's not what I wanted, but I didn't know about it. So thanks! Another thing I've learnt today :)

Comment: Then just remove unwanted items and don't care about 'empty cells'. NSMutableArray use object chains - it very differs from C lang array :)

Comment: It's not a "bad idea" -- it's impossible to put `NULL`/`nil` into an `NSArray` at all.